# Am I accessing this vector variable correctly?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, std, declaration

I'm trying to find where my code is seg faulting and I think it may have something to do with how I access a variable in the function below:

```
/****************************************************************
 * Function for getting the value of a square.
**/
int Board::getSquare(int row, int col)
{
  vector<int> rowVector = this->theBoard[row];
//gets desired row from theBoard
  return rowVector[col];
//returns desired column of the row from theBoard
} // int Board::getSquare(int row, int col)
```

theBoard is a private variable of the class Board:

```
private:
/****************************************************************
 * Variables.
**/
  vector< vector<int> > theBoard;
```

Do I need to separately declare and initiate the rowVector variable? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Use `.at` instead of `[]` and see if you get an exception.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this code, although you are copying an entire vector just to get a single value. You can simply `return theBoard[row][col];` As @chris points points out you may be accessing an out-of-bounds element. If you used a debugger you wouldn't have to guess where the segfault was occurring.

Comment: @user657267 I'll switch it to the return statement you put, I actually have something similar to that at another point in my code and I just forgot to do it again at that point. And I tried to use a debugger, but it keeps saying I have no debugging flags even though I put FLAGS = -g -Wall in my makefile. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @JoshBreece did you mean `CFLAGS`? Then again you should be using `CXXFLAGS` unless you aren't relying on the implicit rule for c++ files. Also check that you aren't stripping the symbols on link with `strip` or `-s`.

Comment: do you add items / resize the vectors somewhere. they start out at size 0

Comment: According to your declaration of theBoard, theBoard expects a vector<int>, vector of int while on the constructor you are passing an int data type instead of a vector<int> to theBoard. I suggest you  declare your theBoard like this: vector<int> theBoard;

Comment: @Juniar there is no constructor shown above? the OP is looking at returning an int from a `vector<vector<int>>` not setting one up?

Comment: @user657267 Oh yeah, I'm using CFLAGS. I put a line CFLAGS = -g -Wall in my makefile. I looked in the makefile and there's nothing about strip or -s in there. There's something about clean at the end, but I'm not sure what that does. I didn't write this makefile, it came from my teacher. Is there a certain spot I need to put the CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS thing or can I just put it at the top?

Comment: @JoshBreece This will depend on the recipe that is used for compiling your files, if the makefile is relying on the implicit rule for c++ files then it won't use `CFLAGS` at all, but `CXXFLAGS` (assuming you are using gnu make). If you like you can paste your makefile to pastebin or somewhere similar.

Comment: @user657267 Here is a link to my makefile: http://pastebin.com/QBwsxARv What exactly do you mean "recipe"? And should I just try CXXFLAGS instead then?

Comment: @JoshBreece make has a list of built-in rules for certain files, but in your case you are overriding them with your own recipes (e.g. `$(GPP) -o Main.o -c -DEBUG -D$(LOC) Main.cpp`). Using the built-in rules allows you to simply define the variables to configure the build, but because you're overriding the rules it's not enough to simply define `CFLAGS`, you must include it in your recipes too (e.g. `$(GPP) $(CFLAGS) -o Main.o -c -DEBUG -D$(LOC) Main.cpp`). For c++ files you should be using `CXXFLAGS`, but as you're using your own recipes you can use anything you like, just make sure to use it

Comment: @user657267 I put $(CXXFLAGS) in the recipes in the makefile and then did make again and then gdb the_program and it still said there were no debugging symbols. How exactly do I "use" it besides putting gdb the_program in the console?

Comment: @JoshBreece Did you *set* `CXXFLAGS`? I.e. did you physically change the line `CFLAGS = -g -Wall` to `CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall` as well? If you look at the output of make you should also be able to see the exact recipe it is using to build your object files. If you don't see something like `g++ -g` in there then you know something's wrong.

Comment: @user657267 Yes, I changed it to CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall. The output in the terminal when I make says g++ -03 -Wall -o Board.o -c Board.cpp

Comment: @JoshBreece It's not enough to use `-g` on main.o only, you must add `$(CXXFLAGS)` to each object file you build. Forget about using make for the time being and build your app with `g++ -g -O0 -Wall -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -DEBUG -DLOC -lm -lc main.cpp DoTheWork.cpp Board.cpp ../../Utilities/ScanLine.cpp ../../Utilities/Scanner.cpp ../../Utils.cpp -o Aprog`. Alternatively get rid of `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` and just add `-g` to `GPP` (also disable optimisations).

Answer (score 1):

You should check sizes or use `.at` to access variables that you are not sure of, ie:

```
if (this->theBoard.size() > row)
    if (this->theBoard[row].size() > col)
        return this->theBoard[row][col];
```

or use `try catch` with `.at`

```
try {
   return this->theBoard.at(row).at(col);
catch (...)
{
   std::cerr << "wrong row col size" << std::endl
}
```

just an example/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `this` pointer inside a class member function to reference a class member variable, so

```
int Board::getSquare( int row, int col)
{
  vector<int> rowVector = this->theBoard[ row];
```

is equivalent to

```
int Board::getSquare(int row, int col)
{
  vector<int> rowVector = theBoard[ row];
```

Apart from this you are correct. Now, `std::vector::operator[]` returns a reference to the element ( because otherwise statements like std::vector v(1); v[0]=7; wouldn't compile - it is illegal to modify the return value of a function that returns a built-in type, and even if it were OK you would change a copy not original object), so you can simply write

```
int Board::getSquare( int row, int col)
{
    return theBoard[row][col];
}
```

if you are sure that you won't access out of bound elements. If you cannot guarantee such invariant add check for this, for example

```
int Board::getSquare( int row, int col)
{
    if ( !( row < theBoard.size())
      throw std::out_of_range( "invalid row");

    if ( !( col < theBoard[ row].size())
      throw std::out_of_range( "invalid col");

    return theBoard[ row][ col];
}
```

or use `std::vector::at` instead of `operator[]`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector